# Find the percentage of male and female students with classes, pointers, and a vector

Tags: c++, pointers

I've introduced a student class with the data members of `string name`, `char gender`, and `double gpa`.

The class looks like this:

```
class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(string name, char gender, double gpa);
    void setName(string name);
    void setGender(char gender);
    void setGpa(double gpa);
    string getName();
    char getGender();
    double getGpa();
private:
    string name;
    char gender;
    double gpa;
};
```

I have another class Department

```
class Department {
public:
    Department();
    Department(string department_name);
    void setDepartment(string department_name);
    string getDepartment();
    void claimMajor(Student*);
    void demography_by_gender();
private:
    vector<Student*> majors;
    string department_name;
};
```

This is my int main

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
Student* mike = new Student("Mike", 'M', 1.9);
Student* alexa = new Student("Alexa", 'F', 2.2);
Student* brook = new Student("Brook", 'F', 3.9);
Student* sam = new Student("Sam", 'F', 2.1);
Student* kevin = new Student("Kevin", 'M', 0.7);
Student* john = new Student("John", 'M', 2.5);
Student* jen = new Student("Jen", 'F', 1.8);
Department* csci = new Department("CSCI");
csci->claimMajor(mike);
csci->claimMajor(alexa);
csci->claimMajor(brook);
csci->claimMajor(sam);
csci->claimMajor(kevin);
csci->claimMajor(john);
csci->claimMajor(jen);
csci->demography_by_gender();

return 0;
}
```

The vector stores all the Student pointers, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to compute the percentage of male and female students using `demography_by_gender()`, then printing out the results.

Comment: What's your specific problem? The math, or how to apply it in that function from accessing the data in that class?

Comment: How to apply it in the function from accessing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    float Department::demography_by_gender(char gender)
    {
      size_t found = 0;
      if (majors->empty()) return 0.f;
      else for (auto student: majors) {
        if (student->gender == gender) found++;
      }
      return float(found) / majors->size();
    }
```